# Routing not working .net mvc api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

Did a lot of reading around this but no existing fixes work for me. 
I am trying to hit an api endpoint from a apiClient project but I keep getting the error message:  No action was found on the controller 'UserApi' that matches the request.
I'm able to debug into the api controller but it just won't hit the method.

Client:

```
 public async Task<bool> UserExists(UserDto dto)
    {
        var postUrl = $"{BaseUri}UserApi/user-exists";
        var json = await PostAsync(new Uri(postUrl), dto);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(json);
    }
```

Api controller:

```
[Route("api/UserApi")]
public class UserApiController : ApiController
{

    public UserApiController()
    {
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("user-exists")]
    public async Task<bool> UserExists([FromBody]UserDto dto)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "ApiAction",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{dto}",
             defaults: new { dto = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
    }
```

The bottom routing configuration is the one I'm trying to use. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. You state that you're trying to use the routes declared in RegisterRoutes. But you also use attribute routing. Which do you want to use? And if you want attribute routing, why didn't you call MapHttpAttributeRoutes as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)?

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I've set up routing on my own, i thought I had to apply the attributes and the RegisterRoutes was just for defining the format of the routes to look for?

Comment: So in the documentation it states: Attribute routing can be combined with convention-based routing. To define convention-based routes, call the MapHttpRoute method.
This is the way I've tried to set this up

Comment: You need to *decide* which to use. You can use them both at the same time for different routes. But not for the same route. If you intend to use attribute routing, then don't state in your question "the bottom routing configuration is the one I'm trying to use".

Comment: When i said the bottom routing configuration is the one I'm trying to use, I meant the second route in RegisterRoutes. The Http one. I'll try to remove all routing from register routes and see if the attributes alone works, as I think that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: so now with all route mapping removed from registerRoutes, I'm still getting the same error as before : No action was found on the controller 'UserApi' that matches the request.

Comment: So I still think I have an underlying issue with the actual routing attributes

Comment: Change routes order.  Default route must be last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first comment on the original post solved half my issue - I was trying to configure routing two different ways. I removed all my code from RegisterRoutes and used

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

in WebApiConfig.
I also needed to use the RoutePrefix attribute on the api controller instead of just Route - which is to be used on the controller methods. working now

Answer (score 0):

1.In Global.asax.cs just comment
//RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
As you are using web api no need of this route configuration
2.In WebApiConfig.cs use below line only
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);